SpringData: repository is null
I'm working on a project that requires a login page. I'm trying to save a new user on a crud repository, but whatever I do I get a this.userRepository is null. This happens when I call UserManager.createUser in another class.
UserManager
package milligroup.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;

import milligroup.services.UtenteService;
import milligroup.services.UtenteServiceImpl;

public class UserManager implements UserDetailsManager{
    @Autowired
    UtenteService userService = new UtenteServiceImpl();
    public void createUser(UserDetails userBean, String email) {
        userService.saveUser(new Utente(email, userBean.getUsername(), userBean.getPassword()));
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(String email) {
        Utente u = (Utente) userService.search(email);
        userService.delete(u);
    }

    @Override
    public void changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userExists(String email) {
        Utente u = (Utente) userService.search(email);
        if(u == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void createUser(UserDetails user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserDetails user) {
        //chiama service
        
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    
}


UtenteServiceImpl
package milligroup.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import milligroup.models.Utente;
import milligroup.models.UtenteRepository;

@Service
public class UtenteServiceImpl implements UtenteService{
    @Autowired
    private UtenteRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public Utente saveUser(Utente u) {
        return userRepository.save(u);
    }

    @Override
    public Utente search(String email) {
        return (Utente) userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Utente u) {
        userRepository.delete(u);       
    }

}


UtenteService
package milligroup.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import milligroup.models.Utente;
import milligroup.models.UtenteRepository;

@Service
public interface UtenteService{
    Utente saveUser(Utente u);

    Utente search(String email);

    void delete(Utente u);
}


UtenteRepository
package milligroup.models;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * 
 */
@Repository
public interface UtenteRepository extends CrudRepository<Utente, Long>{
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Query("select u from Utente u where lower(u.email) = :searchTerm")   
    List<Utente> findByEmail(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm);
}


I tried removing the creation of a UtenteServiceImpl in UserManager but then I get a this.userService is null.

Spring Autowired only works in managed beans... UserManager is a pojo

I tried making it a bean by making userService private, adding a blank constructor, a getter and a setter, and implementing serializable, but it still doesn't work
